# How to separate data items in Repeater?

Tags: repeater, separator

I'm using a Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label  Text='<%# Eval("History_Info") %>'</asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The results that I get from DataSource are list of strings.

ex:
Date:08/07/2014, User: UserName, LoginNumber: 000 ......

How can I show it like that :

Date: 08/07/2014

User: UserName

LoginNumber: 000

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying `History_Info` is a list of strings separated by commas i.e. one big string?

Comment: Yes, is a one big string, separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a replace during binding, so that commas are replaced with line breaks, like so:

```
<asp:Label  Text='<%# ((string)Eval("History_Info")).Replace(",", @"<br/>") %>'</asp:Label>
```

This will throw error if `History_Info` is null, so you need to handle that as well, perhaps by using null-coalescing operator (`??`) or an explicit check.